# JSONDecodeError when using wikipedia-api

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, wikipedia-api

I am trying to use Python wikipedia-api. I am getting error like below.

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I did not find any solution for this error.

```
import wikipedia

page = wikipedia.page("google")#interpreter shows error for this line
print(page.summary)
```

I expect the output like below:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google
```

Comment: It is working fine for me.. Is this the exact code you are trying?

Comment: Yes it is. I have tried many code examples related to wikipedia-api but they did not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a restriction on access to wikipedia from your country, this will cause the error.

You can resolve the error using vpn on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did not think that way. I suppose we must change url request.